# Test if Callable points at specific member function

Tags: c++, casting

I want to test if a _Callable `__f` is a (pointer to a) specific non-static member function `memberfuncA`.
I can test that with `__f == &MyClass::memberfuncA`, but only if I get no memberfuncB in the way, as in the example below, which results in a compiler error.
I tried to use std::is_convertible to make sure the cast will compile, but that didn't work; same with typeid().

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {};
class B {};

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {
        A a;
        B b;
        push_exec(&MyClass::memberfuncA, this, a);
        push_exec(&MyClass::memberfuncB, this, b);
    }

    template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    void push_exec(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
    {
        // Test if typeid is the same
        if(typeid(__f) == typeid(&MyClass::memberfuncA))
            // Test if types are castable
            if(std::is_convertible<typeof __f, typeof &MyClass::memberfuncA>::value)
                // Test if __f is actually pointing to a specific member function (compiler error)
                if(__f == &MyClass::memberfuncA)
                    return;
    }

    void memberfuncA(A a) { }
    void memberfuncB(B b) { }
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;
}
```

Compiler output is

```
g++ --std=gnu++11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/callable_test.d" -MT"src/callable_test.o" -o "src/callable_test.o" "../src/callable_test.cpp"
../src/callable_test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void MyClass::push_exec(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (MyClass::*)(B); _Args = {MyClass* const, B&}]’:
../src/callable_test.cpp:13:49:   required from here
../src/callable_test.cpp:24:24: error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘void (MyClass::*)(B)’ and ‘void (MyClass::*)(A)’ lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
                 if(__f == &MyClass::memberfuncA)
                        ^
../src/callable_test.cpp:24:24: error: cannot convert ‘__f’ from type ‘void (MyClass::*)(B)’ to type ‘void MyClass::*’
../src/callable_test.cpp:24:24: error: cannot convert ‘&MyClass::memberfuncA’ from type ‘void (MyClass::*)(A)’ to type ‘void MyClass::*’
make: *** [src/callable_test.o] Error 1
```

Any idea how I can check if `__f == &MyClass::memberfuncA`?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with two underscores (`__f`) are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Look up "partial template specialization" for an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** want compare `__f` and `&MyClass::memberfunc`, you can cast they to `void *`

```
            if( ((void*)__f) == ((void*)&MyClass::memberfuncA) )
                return;
```

Checking with `std::is_convertible` don't work because it's a compilation problem, not a run-time error. I mean: even if `std::is_convertible` `value` is `false`, the compiler try to compile the following `if`.

You could try `std::is_convertible` with SFINAE; something like this (**EDIT**: corrected version):

```
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
   typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_convertible<_Callable, void (MyClass::*)(A)>::value, void>::type push_exec(_Callable && __f, _Args && ... __args)
    {
      // do something
    }

template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
   typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_convertible<_Callable, void (MyClass::*)(A)>::value, void>::type push_exec(_Callable && __f, _Args && ... __args)
    {
      // do something else
    }
```

Comment: std::enable_if would need to know __f before it's declared...
The `void*` works! but it gives a warning: converting from ‘void (MyClass::*)(A)’ to ‘void*’ [-Wpmf-conversions]
Can I avoid that warning somehow?

Comment: @Laurenz the warning is suggesting that what you wan to do is a bad idea. Perhaps it's time to redesign the solution?

Comment: @Laurenz: I'm agree with Richard Hodges: it's a bad idea (was the meaning of my "really"). About `std::enable_if`... sorry, yesterday I was in a hurry (I used the variables in it? I can't believe it); now I've corrected the example.

Comment: Thanks! I did redesign the solution to use a mutex instead ;)